# Landmasking in SAR geotiff image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, mask, conda, geotiff

I am trying to mask the land in a satellite (SAR) grayscale geotiff image. The functionality is available in rsgislib, but it works on Linux and I am working on conda python 3.5 (Windows) and not able to find a possible way out.
Kindly guide as to how the land can be masked out in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way out :

First we have to download an appropriate shapefile of the region we wish to mask,
then there is a beautiful functionality available in gdal called as `gdalwarp`. We need to just open the **anaconda prompt** and from there just type in :`

```
gdalwarp -cutline shapefile_name.shp original_image.tif output_filename.tif
```

Now, the image with borderlines of the land will get saved in the file `output_filename.tif`
This is the file which contains the land portion and the ocean is masked out.

Then the procedure becomes fairly simple mask out the land by subtracting the `output_filename.tif` image from original image.

We will get the image of the ocean part with land portion in black, after that we can make the land portion as `NaN`.